# 'Zipping' two reactive streams where elements are reusable

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

Suppose I have two streams of A's and B's.

Stream 1: A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6
Stream B: B1, B2, B3, B4

Timeline: B1 > A1 > A2 > B2 > A3 > A4 > B3 > A5
Desired output: [B1 & A1], [A2 & B2], [B2 & A3], [A4 & B3], [B3 & A5], [A6 & B4]

This mirrors a real life process where B's are double sided and stacked together. For example,

```
---- B1 ----]
            |-1
---- A1 ----]

---- A2 ----]
            ]-2
---- B2 ----|]
            ]|-3
---- A3 ---- ]

---- A4 ----]
            |-4
---- B3 ----]]
             |-5
---- A5 ---- ]

---- A6 ----]
            |-6
---- B4 ----]
```

Grouping 1 is characteristic of the initial pair. Grouping 6 is characteristic of the terminal pairing. Groups 2/3 and 4/5 can be repeated.

I'm looking for ideas on how to achieve this with RxJava2.

Thanks, Dan.

EDIT

I made a test case:

```
import java.util.Objects;

import org.junit.Test;

import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction;
import io.reactivex.processors.FlowableProcessor;
import io.reactivex.processors.ReplayProcessor;

public class BuildControllerTest {
    @Test
    public void testProductBlanketSequencing() throws Exception {           
        final String a1="A1", a2="A2", a3="A3", a4="A4", a5="A5", a6="A6";
        final String b1="B1", b2="B2", b3="B3", b4="B4";

        class AB {
            String a;
            String b;

            public AB(String a, String b) {
                this.a = a;
                this.b = b;
            }

            @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                if(getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
                if( ! Objects.equals(a, ((AB)obj).a)) return false;
                if( ! Objects.equals(b, ((AB)obj).b)) return false;
                return true;
            }
        }

        final FlowableProcessor<String> a = ReplayProcessor.create();
        final FlowableProcessor<String> b = ReplayProcessor.create();

        b.onNext(b1);
        a.onNext(a1);

        a.onNext(a2);
        b.onNext(b2);
        a.onNext(a3);

        a.onNext(a4);
        b.onNext(b3);
        a.onNext(a5);

        a.onNext(a6);
        b.onNext(b4);

        a.onComplete(); b.onComplete();

        Flowable.zip(a, b, new BiFunction<String, String, AB>() {
            @Override public AB apply(String t1, String t2) throws Exception {
                return new AB(t1, t2);
            }
        })
        .test()
        .assertResult(
                new AB(a1, b1), 
                new AB(a2, b2), 
                new AB(a3, b2), 
                new AB(a4, b3), 
                new AB(a5, b3), 
                new AB(a6, b4));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your example it is not clear what condition drives pairing.

When we use [`zip`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) the pair is formed as soon as both sources has next item:

```
(A1, B1), (A2, B2), (A3, B3), (A4, B4)
```

If we use [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) the pair is formed when there is next item in any source:

```
(A1, B1), (A2, B1), (A2, B2), (A3, B2), (A4, B2), (A4, B3), (A5, B3), (A6, B3), (A6, B4)
```

---

For me it looks like you want to combine sources but take not every pair. You can remove extra pairs depending on business rules.

The extra rule can be time, then take look at [sampling](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html).

```
Flowable.combineLatest(a, b, (t1, t2) -> new AB(t1, t2))
        .throttleLast(1, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
```

it will take latest result from combined pairs every time interval

```
(A1, B1), (A4, B3), (A5, B3), (A6, B3), (A6, B4)
```

If extra rules is to have unique values from source A and posible repeats from B then you can use [`distinct`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html)

```
Flowable.combineLatest(a, b, (t1, t2) -> new AB(t1, t2))
        .distinct(ab -> ab.a)

(A1, B1), (A2, B1), (A3, B2), (A4, B2), (A5, B3), (A6, B3)
```

Comment: combineLatest seems to be handy for my circumstance, though so far I've struggled to get it to produce what I need. One problem is controlling the sequencing in a test case. I have though got it to work with zip and doubling the Bs after the first one: final AtomicBoolean reset = new AtomicBoolean(true); zip(a, b.flatMap(t -> reset.getAndSet(false) ? Flowable.just(t) : Flowable.just(t, t)), (t1,t2)->new AB(t1,t2));
But presumably this is bad?

Comment: Ah, I didn't understood that you want to repeat every element in B except first one. It should work then.

Comment: Duplicating the Bs wasn't the goal, but it does turn out to produce the correct sequence (ignoring the first and last ones) when zipped. My problem is more elaborate than this example, however, and combineLatest has proven very useful in that scenario. Thanks!